# How can I import external *.jar in spring mvc project using maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, jar

I followed this correct answer in [how to add local jar using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project), But I get 404 not found.
POM.Xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tn.mass</groupId>
        <artifactId>massTer</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

[eclipse console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iztL4.png)

Comment: The exception you posted rather points to a version conflict within your Spring dependencies. Make sure that you use the same version for all Spring libs. You can check that by executing `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: On other note, please do not link stack traces and code here. Instead edit your question and include the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your .m2 folder if massTer.jar is present with correct group id and version. Ideally if you are owning the source project massTer then I would suggest you to user maven-install-plugin to get it installed within your .m2 folder when you run mvn clean install over that project. Instead of building the jar and later adding it as mvn install:install

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works well, But once I started to import a specific class In massTer.jar I got this error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: tn.example.MyClass that means JVM can't see MyClass at Runtime, I don't know what can I do ? My POM.xml is correct with massTer

Comment: How do you package your jars? Inside lib folder of your war ?
If so, then is the massTer jar packaged inside the lib ?